# Is there a quantum operation that can transform a superposition of states into its complement?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-algorithms

Given a superposition of states "B" which is a subset of the suoerposition "A" of all possible states of a set of qbits, is there a quantum operation that produces superposition $R= B^C$, the complementary subset of "A", and in the process necessarily destroys "B", to avoid violating the no cloning theorem? If not, is there an operation that can produce an *approximate* complement ${B^C}(Approx)$?

Edit 1: @tsgeorgios has demonstrated in a comment that the proposed operation is not unitary in the general case,  so wouldn't be possible in general.  However, this challenge may be analogous to the challenge of cloning a superposition, which can't be done in general, but can be closely approximated if the set A of states are linearly independent.  That means if there are N qbits, there can only be N states in the superposition A.  Though cumbersome, any method for approximating the complement of information encoded in B would be potentially useful.

Comment: @MarkS points out, in a comment to a related question, that the complement to the universal set is the null set, which might not have any meaning in reference to superpositions of states in a set of qbits.  That's a good point.  However, in this context maybe a single fully determined state would correspond to the null set.

Comment: B must be a proper subset then? If not then if you have a state which is a superposition of all possible states (says the uniform superposition state) then its complement would be nothing... which is not possible.

Comment: In practice, B would always be a proper subset.

Comment: If i understand it correctly, the output for all states of the form $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} (| 00 \rangle + | 01 \rangle + e^{i\phi} |10 \rangle) $ should be $ |11 \rangle $, right? But then, this is not a unitary operation. This means that you can't do what you ask for an arbitary superposition of an (arbitary) subset B.

Comment: Why is it not a unitary operation?

Comment: @BlackHat18 Take, for example, the states $ |\phi_\pm \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \big(|00 \rangle + |01 \rangle \pm |10 \rangle \big)$ and let's say that the outputs are $ U | \phi_\pm \rangle = e^{ia_\pm} |11 \rangle $. If U was unitary, it should hold that $ \frac{1}{3} = \langle \phi_- | \phi_+ \rangle = \langle \phi_- |U^\dagger U| \phi_+ \rangle = e^{i(a_+ - a_-)} $, but this can not be the case. 

In general, the operation in question is probably not even linear since $ (B_1 \cup B_2)^c = B_1^c 
 \cap B_2^c $